# Changing MySQL from latin1 encoding to UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, database, character-encoding

I recently realized that I made a big mistake and encoded things on the front end in UTF-8 and on the DB side to latin1.

I am thinking to switch my MySQL db to UTF-8.  Is there a "good practice" of doing such a procedure?  Any recommended steps I can take?  What are the pitfalls I should watch out for?

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major (and most common) pitfall would be hoping that `ALTER DATABASE … DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` or `ALTER TABLE … DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` will change the encoding of the existing columns.

These statements only affect the tables and columns created after you issued these statements.

You should `ALTER` each table separately, using

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

Comment: that will spoil all non-latin characters, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ColShrapnel: it definitely would if they found a way to get into a `latin1` column. `Latin1` is a subset of `UTF8`.

Comment: no, it's not, AFAIK. and you can store any characters into latin1 table actually.

Comment: @ColShrapnel: could you please name a character which is in `latin1` but not in `UTF8`? An attempt to insert a non-latin1 character into a `latin1` column will result in a warning `Incorrect string value` and the character being replaced by a `?` sign.

Comment: no, it wont' as long as your client encoding match table encoding. and latin1 is default one

Comment: @ColShrapnel: Please try inserting a Russian character into a `latin1` table and see what happens. Use any client encoding you want.

Comment: there is no 'Russian' charset. there are some charsets supports cyrillic letters, cp1251 for example. and it goes into latin1 database perfectly. Note a condition from my previous comment

Comment: @ColShrapnel: Show, don't tell. Please try inserting a Russian character into a `latin1` table. Post a dump then.

Comment: @ColShrapnel: I assume there will be no dump?

Answer (score 3):

I found one trick in the internet (so it's not mine but i forget where i get this from) using a dump with missing encoding and then re-import that "blank" dump in again with the right encoding.

Helps only if all the data in the tables are really in the correct encoding (for the re-import)
If not you will loose data: every field value will be truncated after the first illegal encoded character.

I got this for the ß character. Still found no way around that. Should be doable with something like "ignore worng characters" or similar, i think...

Example steps for a MsSQL table in latin1  with utf-8 encoded content (for a linux shell) are:

```
mysqldump --opt --quote-names --skip-set-charset --default-character-set=latin1 mydatabase > /tmp/dump.sql
mysql --default-character-set=utf8 mydatabase < /tmp/dump.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this from my bookmarks. It's a bit old, but might still suite your needs:

http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html